# SQL Query with coalesce inside join and subquery returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

My Query is returning null where I would like a 0. I think it has something to do with the coalesce being inside of the subquery but I cannot get anything to change. the query in question:

```
SELECT c.post_id, c.post_name, c.post_content, c.post_datetime, c.user_name, 
    p.like_count, 
    p.dislike_count, 
    s.comment_count
FROM posts c 
    LEFT JOIN (
       select post_id, 
              sum(like_count) like_count,
              sum(dislike_count) dislike_count
       from post_likes
       group by post_id
    ) p ON c.post_id = p.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN (
       select post_id, COALESCE(sum(comment_count),0) comment_count
       from comments
       group by post_id
    ) s ON c.post_id = s.post_id 
WHERE c.user_name = 'test'
```

It is returning the correct sum but COALESCE seems to have no affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Move the `COALESCE` up to the outer query and you should be good. The reason it's not working is the `COALESCE` only applies to rows inside the `s` derived table expression. If there's no matching row in `s` from the left outer join with `c`, then nothing from `s`, including the coalesced column, will return from `s`. You'll get NULLs for all columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help and insight this worked perfectly in the end, at first I put coalesce on the outside query without defining a column name and it didn't work (obviously!) but after defining the desired column name I got the correct results!